# c - Segmentation fault with flex yacc and yyparse

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, bison, flex-lexer, ansi-c

I was trying to implement a compiler using flex and yacc. When I use yyparse() console return "segmentation fault whith core dumped". How to fix this?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *sourcefile = (char *) calloc(strlen(argv[1]), sizeof(char));
    strcpy(sourcefile, argv[1]);

    yyin = fopen(sourcefile, "r");

    listing = stdout; /* send listing to screen */
    yyrestart(yyin);
    yyparse();

    fclose(yyin);

    return 0;
}
```

Warnings in compile:

```
parse.y: In function ‘yyparse’:
parse.y:103:19: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  | OP_SREDNIK {$$ = OP_SREDNIK;}
                   ^
parse.y:104:19: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  | READ ID OP_SREDNIK {$$ = READ;}
                   ^
parse.y:107:19: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  | ZWROC OP_SREDNIK {$$ = ZWROC;}
                   ^
parse.y:114:19: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  | THIS {$$ = THIS;}
                   ^
parse.y:115:19: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  | SUPER {$$ = SUPER;}
                   ^
parse.y:121:19: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  | WyrazeniePostfiksowe OP_KROPKA ID {$$ = $3;}
```

parse.y (yacc)

```
Instrukcja : Wyrazenie OP_SREDNIK {$$ = $1;}
    | ZlozonaInstrukcja OP_SREDNIK {$$ = $1;}
    | WyrazeniePostfiksowe OP_PRZYPISANIA Wyrazenie OP_SREDNIK {$$ = $3;}
    | Blok {$$ = $1;}
    | DELETE Wyrazenie OP_SREDNIK {$$ = $2;}
    | OP_SREDNIK {$$ = OP_SREDNIK;}
    | READ ID OP_SREDNIK {$$ = READ;}
    | WRITE Wyrazenie OP_SREDNIK {$$ = $2;}
    | ZWROC Wyrazenie OP_SREDNIK {$$ = $2;}
    | ZWROC OP_SREDNIK {$$ = ZWROC;}
;
```

Comment: You should allocate 1 more byte in `sourcefile` to hold the terminating `\0`: [strlen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) doesn't count it, but [strcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncpy.3.html) does. It's bugs like these that cause segmentation faults.

Comment: Or, more simply, don't bother copying `argv[1]`. There is no need to make a copy just to provide the string to `fopen`. But more importantly, you must check the return value of `fopen`; if it returns NULL, then any attempt to use `yyin` will definitely result in a segfault.

Comment: Kenney: How about that: "(char *) calloc(strlen(argv[1])+1, sizeof(char));" ?
rici: fopen returns something, not NULL in this case.

Comment: @niesuch: If the problem is not the return value of `fopen`, then I think you'll need to reveal something of what is going on in your lexer and parser. (Unfortunately, my crystal ball is in the shop for repairs so I can't quite make out what is going on in your code.) You might want to start by using a debugger and trying to figure out the problem yourself. Enabling flex and bison tracing may help you find out where the problem is happening.

Comment: @rici: I edited my topic. Can you help me?